# nginx ingress Jenkins path rewrite configuration not working

Tags: nginx, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed Jenkins on Kubernetes and am trying to configure the nginx ingress for it.

Assume I want it to be available at https://myip/jenkins

This is my initial ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /jenkins
        backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
```

With this when I access `https://myip/jenkins` I am redirected to `http://myip/login?from=%2F`.

When accessing `https://myip/jenkins/login?from=%2F` it stays on that page but none of the static resources are found since they are looked for at https://myip/static...

Comment: I have seen similar before with a UI not liking its target being rewritten. I guess you can't remove the rewrite-target without putting it on just / and presumably you don't want to do that as then you'd need a dedicated IP/host for jenkins. 
The public jenkins helm chart seems to want a dedicated host for jenkins. https://technologyconversations.com/2018/06/01/deploying-jenkins-to-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-helm/ You could set up DNS and point it to myip. If myip is a public IP then you could even do this quick and dirty using jenkins.myip.nip.io as nip.io would give you free wildcard dns

Comment: For the moment we need to get by without DNS, it seems to be a Jenkins UI problem. I worked around it setting the jenkins image context path and not relying on the ingress rewrite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I solved it configuring the Jenkins image context path without the need to use the ingress rewrite annotations:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: jenkins
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jenkins
      containers:
      - image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        name: jenkins
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: "http-server"
        - containerPort: 50000
          name: "jnlp"
        resources: {}
        env:
        - name: JENKINS_OPTS
          value: --prefix=/jenkins
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/var/jenkins_home"
          name: jenkins-storage
status: {}
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prfl-apps-devops-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /jenkins
        backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: Just want to leave a comment for those who will try this solution with Jenkins operator: it won't work as it breas Seed Jobs part due to unable to automatically handle new Jenkins URL in cluster. But it still work if you just need to expose Jenkins with custom URL.

Comment: For me worked , after adding `httpListenAddress` to the env `env:  - name: JENKINS_OPTS                     value: "--prefix=/jenkins --httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0" `

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the JenkinsCI Helm chart (jenkinsci/jenkins), and @codependent's answer set me on the right track.

The base uri can be set during a helm install or helm upgrade:

```
helm install jenkins jenkinsci/jenkins --set controller.jenkinsUriPrefix='/jenkins'
```

or, if you've already installed Jenkins:

```
helm upgrade jenkins jenkinsci/jenkins --set controller.jenkinsUriPrefix='/jenkins'
```

Answer (score 0):

the above solution won't work directly as jenkins controller pod will fail on heathchecks if any. check this deployment.yaml below with ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: devops-tools
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins-server
    spec:
      securityContext:
            fsGroup: 1000 
            runAsUser: 1000
      serviceAccountName: jenkins-admin
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "6Gi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            requests:
              memory: "500Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          env:
            - name: JENKINS_OPTS
              value: "--prefix=/jenkins --httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0"
          ports:
            - name: httpport
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: jnlpport
              containerPort: 50000
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: "/jenkins/login"
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 90
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: "/jenkins/login"
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 3
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-data
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home         
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: jenkins-pv-claim
```

ingress.yaml is as follows "

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
  name: jenkins
  namespace: devops-tools
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host:  example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /jenkins
        backend:
          service:
            name: jenkins-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

with applying above changes you will be able to access your jenkins on http://example.com/jenkins